# conditionally addCircleMarkers to leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a bunch of reactive filters based on user inputs. I want to addCircleMarkers on my leaflet map only if the filters do not return a NULL value. How can I conditionally addCircleMarkers to a leaflet map in Shiny? Right now it seems that it only plots the results from the second filter instead of both even if user inputs are not NULL for both. My guess is that the second addCircleMarkers function is overwriting the first instead of adding more circles to the map. Here's my server code below:

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {


relig_pal <- colorFactor("magma", unique(all_cleaned$religion))
denom_pal <- colorFactor("viridis", unique(all_cleaned$denom))

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
  input$years_map
  input$map_button
  isolate({
    map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() 
    if(!is.null(geography_1())) {
    marker_1 <- addCircleMarkers(map = map, data = geography_1(),
                     radius = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), log(religion_population), 
                                      log(denom_pop)),
                     color = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), relig_pal(religion),
                                     denom_pal(denom)),
                     label = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), 
                                            paste("Religion:",religion,
                                                  "Population:",religion_population),
                                            paste("Denomination:", denom,               
                                                  "Population:", denom_pop)) 
    )
    }
    if(!is.null(geography_2())) {
    marker_1 %>% addCircleMarkers(data = geography_2(),
                     radius = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), log(religion_population), 
                                      log(denom_pop)),
                   color = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), relig_pal(religion),
                                   denom_pal(denom)),
                   label = ~ifelse(is.na(denom), 
                                          paste("Religion:", religion,
                                                "Population:", religion_population),             
                                          paste("Denomination:", denom,              
                                                "Population:", denom_pop))
    )
    }
  })
})

year <- reactive({
  req(input$years_map)
  all_cleaned %>% filter(year == input$years_map)
})

religion_1 <- reactive({
  req(input$religion_1_map)
  if(input$religion_1_map == "All") {
    year()
  }
  else if(input$religion_1_map == "None") {
    return()
  }
  else {
    year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_1_map)
  }
})

denom_1 <- reactive({
  req(input$denom_1_map)
  if(input$denom_1_map == "All") {
    religion_1()
  }
  else if(input$denom_1_map == "None") {
    religion_1() %>% filter(is.na(denom))
  }
  else {
    religion_1() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_1_map)
  }
})

geography_1 <- reactive({
  req(input$geography_1_map)
  if(input$geography_1_map == "All") {
    denom_1()
  }
  else if(input$geography_1_map == "None") {
    return()
  }
  else {
    denom_1() %>% filter(country_name == input$geography_1_map)
  }
})


religion_2 <- reactive({
  req(input$religion_2_map)
  if(input$religion_2_map == "All") {
    year()
  }
  else if(input$religion_2_map == "None") {
    return()
  }
  else {
    year() %>% filter(religion == input$religion_2_map)
  }
})

denom_2 <- reactive({
  req(input$denom_2_map)
  if(input$denom_2_map == "All") {
    religion_2()
  }
  else if(input$denom_2_map == "None") {
    religion_2() %>% filter(is.na(denom))
  }
  else {
    religion_2() %>% filter(denom == input$denom_2_map)
  }
})

geography_2 <- reactive({
  req(input$geography_2_map)
  if(input$geography_2_map == "All") {
    denom_2()
  }
  else if(input$geography_2_map == "None") {
    return()
  }
  else {
    denom_2() %>% filter(country_name == input$geography_2_map)
  }
})

}
```

Error message:

```
Error:no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I have managed to solve the problem using @Roman Luštrik 's suggestion of storing the first circle marker as a variable and using a placeholder to plot a point of opacity 0 instead of dealing with NULL values whenever nothing is supposed to appear on the plot, which I couldn't quite figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Once you draw markers on the map, you need to save those to a variable (e.g. see how we solved this problem [here](https://github.com/romunov/wolfexplorer/blob/8f5cc167ec1b128e46b889b6b28c85404dec7d22/R/map_add_offspring_markers.R#L23).

For the second question (you should really post them separately), try paste instead of cat, e.g. `paste(statement1, statement2, sep = "\n")`.

Comment: Thanks. After trying your approach which now plots both markers (if none of the inputs return NULL), I realised that my perhaps my problem is that I can't get the application to only add one circle marker if either one of the inputs returns a NULL, which is whenever they select a "None" option. When this happens, it returns an error message: `Error:no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "NULL"`. Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: Try catching an empty string before it's being passed o `addCircleMarkers`. @Sunny

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? How do I make use of this empty string such that no circle markers are added if the filters return a NULL? Sorry but I'm just a beginner.

Comment: @Sunny something along the lines of `if (is.null(x)) {}`. Make a reproducible example and open a new question, this is out of scope of this one.